# Concatenate exon sequences and inserting Ns in between

Tags: python, r, bash, merge, sequence

so I want to perform a somehow complex task with a FASTA file with exon sequences, such as:

```
>MSTRG.1.1_1_30
AAAACGGAGGACCAAGCCGTTTGCCGTACG
>MSTRG.1.1_2_20
CCCGAAGGGCGTTAGTGAGC
>MSTRG.2.1_1_30
ACGGGAGCGTTGTCGACCGGTTGCGAGCGT
>MSTRG.2.1_2_10
AACGGGACCT
>MSTRG.2.1_3_15
AACGTTTGCGTCTCT
```

As can be seen, I have there two transcripts, called MSTRG.1.1 and MSTRG.2.1. The first transcript has two exons, the first is called MSTRG.1.1_1_30, and has a length of 30 letters. The second exon (fragment) has 20 letters. On the contrary, the other transcript has three exons, with 30, 10 and 15 letters each.

There are many more transcripts and with more than 3 exons, up to 20 at maximum more or less.

As you can see, the identifier of the sequence of letters is composed by the name of the transcript "MSTRG.X.X", the numbering of the exon and the length of the string.

What I want to achive is the following:

```
>MSTRG.1.1_1_2
AAAACGGAGGACCAAGCCGTTTGCCGTACGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCCCGAAGGGCGTTAGTGAGC
>MSTRG.2.1_1_2
ACGGGAGCGTTGTCGACCGGTTGCGAGCGTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAACGGGACCT
>MSTRG.2.1_2_3
AACGGGACCTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAACGTTTGCGTCTCT
```

Some explanation:

I want to combine all consecutive exons within the same transcript, so for transcript 1, as there are two exons, just one merged sequence produced from combining exon 1 and 2. For the transcript 2, the result will be two combinations, exons 1 and 2, and exons 2 and 3, and so on, in case of the existance of more exons, so as to get n-1 combinations where n is the number of exons.

Apart from that, I want to introduce a string of Ns between the two combined exons, with length equal to the longest exon of the merged pair + 1. Say, in the first case, introducing a string of 31 Ns between exon 1 and 2. Whereas in the second case, introducing a string of 31 Ns between exon 1 and 2, and a string of 16 Ns between exon 2 and 3.

This is basically my main, and tricky task. Does anyone know or come up to a solution based on Python, BASH, AWK, R, Perl or similar?

I have been trying to solve this but I could not reach a good general solution for looping around the same transcripts while merging them...

Many thanks.

Comment: Is each exon just one line?

Comment: yes, although I can convert it to multiple lines of n characters each if needed. But I think single line is best for what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $transcript;
my $part;
my $exon;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>(.*?\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)_([0-9]+)/) {
        my ($new_transcript, $new_part) = ($1, $2);
        if ($transcript && $transcript eq $new_transcript) {
            say ">$transcript\_$part\_$new_part";

        } else {
            undef $exon;
        }

        $transcript = $new_transcript;
        $part = $new_part;

    } else {
        my $new_exon = $_;
        if ($exon) {
            my $max_length = length $exon;
            $max_length = length $new_exon if length $new_exon > $max_length;
            say $exon, 'N' x ++$max_length, $new_exon;
        }
        $exon = $new_exon;
    }
}
```

It reads the file line by line. The last processed transcript id and its part (and the previous exon, too) are stored in variables. If we encounter a header, we check whether a new transcript starts. If yes, we can forget the previous exon, otherwise we print the header containing the transcript, the previous part and the actual part.

If we read the exon line, if there's an exon to print (which means we aren't in the first part of a transcript), we check the lengths of the old and new exons, select the longer one, and output the exons and N's. Then, we remember the exon for further processing, should another part of the same transcript follow.

Comment: Tested it and worked!! Really fantastic!! Like a charm